# Why is this function from ordinals to cardinals not used more often?

Tags: soft-question, cardinals

The Aleph function $f$ is defined from ordinals to cardinals as $f(x)$=the $x$-th infinite cardinal. However, I think a different function $g$ should be used instead. I define $g(x)$= the $x$-th cardinal. So, for example, for any natural number, $g(n)=n$, and $g(\omega)=\omega$, and $g(\omega+1)=\aleph_1$. So, historically, why was the aleph function used more often than this function? This function seems more natural. This is not really a mathematical question, more like a soft question or philosophical question.

Comment: I think that if we had what you suggest, then all the specialistic literature would introduce something by the name of Normalized Cardinal Function $NCF(\alpha)=g(\omega+\alpha)$ and work throughout with that.

Comment: My guess would be that Cantor felt $\aleph_0$ was a good notation for the first infinite cardinal and took it from there. It is often (but by no means always) the case, that mathematicians respect the notations used by their predecessors, if for no other reason than to minimise confusion. I think it is up to you to say why your alternative proposal is better.